# Keeping a hdd (used for NAS) turned on indefinitely

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, nas

I plan to connect a relatively old external 2.5' backup drive (Seagate STBU1000200 1 TB) to my router for simple NAS (movie, photo sharing on the home network).

It's a hdd, so does that mean it's *not* a flash drive? (Is there a disk that's spinning?) Surprisingly, I could not find an answer to that question. I ask because I am worried that since I won't be removing/unmounting it or turning it off all that much, I might be harming it (I assume a flash drive is not harmed by keeping it plugged in indefinitely).

Question: Does anyone forsee any problem to my hdd by keeping it on, weeks at a time?

Comment: Yes, Seagate drives are usually spinning disks, not flash drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The STBU1000200 is a hard drive, not flash. Flash storage is getting cheaper but anything as big as 1 TB is going to be a lot more expensive than a hard drive.

Hard disks are designed to remain powered on for long periods. Of course it will eventually wear out, but having it spin down too often will actually wear it out faster.

The software provided for the drive allows you to set this timeout, but it will probably not work with your router. Depending on your router and its firmware you may be able to control whether drive goes to sleep and after how long.

If you are using it for media sharing on the network it may be in use fairly often, so it's probably best to just leave it connected and powered on. If you only use it infrequently you can either unplug it when not in use.

Answer (score 1):

Everything wears out eventually.

That said, I've had one computer running here since 2008, 24/7/365 - never sleeping, never spinning down the drives.

It still works just fine.

Most machines will spin down the drives after a period of inactivity, unless you tell them specifically not to.

Comment: Do you think this particular drive can spin itself down? or perhaps routers have a utility to do that?

Comment: You'd have to check the manual.

Comment: @sasha spin-down time is probably a setting on the drive itself.  Seagate has (or had) a utility called [Seagate Dashboard](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/214217en?language=en_US) that might let you configure that.